# PHP Get a part from $string

Tags: php, parsing

could you pls help me to parse the string?

the string is:

`$str = 'http://test.al/admin/?plugin=pages&act=delete&file=test-page';`

It's dynamic and could contain more &-symbols.

I want to get everything but the part starting from "&..."
so the result should be :

```
http://boot.al/admin/?plugin=pages
```

need it to Go Back after deleting a file, to clear additional $_GET params.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My own idea is just to read $_GET as array and use only its 1st element but it seems to be an unprofessional way, tho. May be there is a better solution?

Comment: The URL is always the current request?

Comment: seems like you are aiming to get `plugin=pages`, if so will this part of position be changed ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

```
<?php
$str = 'http://test.al/admin/?plugin=pages&act=delete&file=test-page';
$result = strtok($str, '&');

var_dump($result); // outputs "http://test.al/admin/?plugin=pages"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode('&', $str);
$str = $parts[0];
```

Convert the string to an array by using `&` as delimiter.
The first element of the array will hold the part you need

Comment: IMO, I would use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) instead of `$parts[0]`.

Comment: I think just grabbing the value is quicker than performing the whole shift operation on an array you have no use for after taking the first element. The result will be the same though.

Comment: `[0]` is OK and can be put right after the explode in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for this:

```
$str = 'http://test.al/admin/?plugin=pages&act=delete&file=test-page';

$url_components = parse_url($str);
$get_component = explode("&", $url_components['query']);

$new_str = $url_components['scheme'] . "://" . $url_components['host'] . $url_components['path'] . "?" . $get_component[0];
echo $new_str;
```

Output:

```
http://test.al/admin/?plugin=pages
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using so many lines for something that can be done in a one-liner?

Comment: @RST Just stated an option, plus I'm not sure whether OP got this using URL or string.

Comment: Tnx, I thought I was missing something. `pathinfo()` would probably a better choice then. It has better ways to put the URL together again.